# Daemon threads in Jupyter Notebook don't stop

Tags: multithreading, jupyter-notebook, daemon

I am building a tutorial for my class on Multi-Threading. I have this simple code below which initializes 3 threads. Thread 1,2,3.

Thread 1: simple Timer which waits 4 seconds

Thread 2: simple Timer which waits 2 seconds

Thread 3: simple Timer which waits 6 seconds, but is Daemon.

The main program finishes before the 3rd thread has ended. Because the 3rd thread was deamon I thought it would be killed. Thus, I wonder what is wrong with my code or with the jupyter-notebook. Here is my code.

```
import threading
import logging
import time

def threadLauncher1(name, delay):
    logging.info("Thread %s \t : Starting" %name)
    time.sleep(delay)
    logging.info("Thread %s \t : Finishing" %name)


class threadLauncher2(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, delay):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.delay = delay

    def run(self):
        logging.info("Thread %s \t : Starting" % self.name)
        time.sleep(self.delay)
        logging.info("Thread %s \t : Finishing" % self.name)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO, datefmt="%H:%M:%S")

    threadLauncherFunction1 = threading.Thread(target=threadLauncher1, args=("Timer 1", 4,))
    threadLauncherFunction1.start()

    threadLauncherFunction2 = threadLauncher2("Timer 2", 2)
    threadLauncherFunction2.start()

    threadLauncherFunction3 = threadLauncher2("Timer 3", 6)
    threadLauncherFunction3.setDaemon(True)
    threadLauncherFunction3.start()

    logging.info("Daemon setting is %s on %s" % (str(threadLauncherFunction3.isDaemon()), threadLauncherFunction3.name))

    threadLauncherFunction1.join()
    logging.info("Waited until Timer 1 had finished")
    logging.info("Timer3 should not be able to finish, since it is a daemon Thread")
```

I tried replacing the 3rd thread with a more explicit function.

```
class threadLauncher3(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, delay):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.delay = delay

    def run(self):
        while True:
            logging.info('Thread %s running.' %self.name)
            time.sleep(self.delay)
```

As expected from the previous results, the ouput is:

```
13:19:37: Thread Timer 1     : Starting
13:19:37: Thread Timer 2     : Starting
13:19:37: Thread Timer 3 running.
13:19:37: Daemon setting is True on Timer 3
13:19:38: Thread Timer 3 running.
13:19:39: Thread Timer 2     : Finishing
13:19:39: Thread Timer 3 running.
13:19:40: Thread Timer 3 running.
13:19:41: Thread Timer 1     : Finishing
13:19:41: Waited until Timer 1 had finished
13:19:41: Timer3 should not be able to finish, since it is a daemon Thread
13:19:41: Thread Timer 3 running.
13:19:42: Thread Timer 3 running.
13:19:43: Thread Timer 3 running.
To infinity
```

These two codes work fine on my computer's interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that normal exit processing is when daemon threads are terminated when all the non-daemon threads are gone, but there is no "normal" exit processing done when a cell within jupyter notebook completes executing. You will have to change your `run` method so that it will ultimately return when a "halt" condition is set. For instance, you can add a `do_halt` method that sets a property that will be checked by `run` and then does a `join`:

```
class threadLauncher3(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, delay):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.delay = delay
        self.halt = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.halt:
            logging.info('Thread %s running.' %self.name)
            time.sleep(self.delay)

    def do_halt(self):
        self.halt = True
        self.join()

# code omitted
threadLauncherFunction3.do_halt()
```